# Docusign SOAP API set required field for exisitng pdf field

Tags: php, sdk, docusignapi

We are using docusign soap api to get signature from my customers.we have form field pdf and we're mapping value dynamically using pdftk .we are facing two issues.they are

1. We want to set specific fields as required field that fields already present in pdf.
2. Stop showing template matching popup when docusign open preview

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do these things using the SOAP API. The REST API might be used for these, or you can do them manually. Template Matching can be disabled for the entire account or for specific templates in the account when you go to the template page.